# Array shows values but print_r(array_values) is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting a response from a service and `print_r()` shows an array but it seems to be different from usual arrays.
If I print `array_values` it's are empty.
PHP:

```
    print_r($token); 
//Result: Array ( [{"access_token":"123","token_type":"bearer"}] => ) 
    print_r(array_values($token)); 
//Result: Array ( [0] => )
```

Why are the access_token and token_type values not listed in `array_values`?

Comment: Because that's JSON.

Comment: can you show how `$token` is being generated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is not JSON, It's not because you have a JSON type array. It is because there is NO value in your array.

```
//Result: Array ( [{"access_token":"123","token_type":"bearer"}] => )
```

That array has one index with no value, hence `array_values` shows nothing.  You have created that array incorrectlly :)

Comment: There was an issue with the response! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your outputs with this:

```
$token = array('{"access_token":"123","token_type":"bearer"}' => '');
```

That is because you have an array with the key

```
'{"access_token":"123","token_type":"bearer"}'
```

but no value.

To access the JSON string in the array key, you could do this:

```
$keys = array_keys($token);
print_r($keys[0]);
```

To access the JSON object, you can further do

```
print_r(json_decode($keys[0]));
```

Output:

```
(
    [access_token] => 123
    [token_type] => bearer
)
```

**Demo:** [Fiddle](http://tehplayground.com/#MIwM1cZBS)